# OpenGLES 3.0 Cannot render to a texture larger than the screen size

Tags: opengl-es, textures, framebuffer, opengl-es-3.0

I have made an image below to indicate my problem. I render my scene to an offscreen framebuffer with a texture the size of the screen. I then render said texture to a screen-filling quad. This produces the case 1 on the image. I then run the exact same program, but with with a texture size, let's say, 1.5 times greater (enough to contain the entire smiley), and afterwards render it once more to the screen-filling quad. I then get result 3, but I expected to get result 2.

I remember to change the viewport according to the new texture size before rendering to the texture, and reset the viewport before drawing the quad. I do NOT understand, what I am doing wrong.

[problem shown as an image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atgU4.png)

To summarize, this is the general flow (too much code to post it all):

1. Create `MSAAframebuffer` and `ResolveFramebuffer` (Resolve contains the texture).
2. Set `glViewport(0, 0, Width*1.5, Height*1.5)`
3. Bind `MSAAframebuffer` and render my scene (the smiley).
4. Blit the `MSAAframebuffer` into the `ResolveFramebuffer`
5. Set `glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height)`, bind the texture and render my quad.

Note that all the MSAA is working perfectly fine. Also both buffers have the same dimensions, so when I blit it is simply: `glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, Width*1.5, Height*1.5, 0, 0, Width*1.5, Height*1.5, ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit, BlitFramebufferFilter.Nearest)`

Hope someone has a good idea. I might get fired if not :D

Comment: Do you have a scissor state set to your screen's resolution perhaps?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. However, I found that I actually used an AABB somewhere else in the code to determine what to render; and this AABB was computed from the "small viewport's size". Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I actually used an AABB somewhere else in the code to determine what to render; and this AABB was computed from the "small viewport's size". Stupid mistake.